# Weird Compiler Errors

Tags: c++, class, enums, compiler-errors

I'm getting a large amount of errors with the below code that I can't understand.

> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11

They all seem to be similar to the above, just with a different number at the end. This is most likely due to me trying to remove one of the class definitions from within the code.

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

static const float MAX_SATCHEL_VOLUME = 0.20; // in m^3
static const float MAX_CARTON_VOLUME = 0.50; // in m^3
static const float MAX_PALLET_VOLUME = 2.00;// in m^3

static const float SATCHEL_COST_PER_KILO = 2.00; // in dollars
static const float CARTON_COST_PER_KILO = 1.00; // in dollars
static const float PALLET_COST_PER_KILO = 0.50; // in dollars

class freight
{
    public:
        enum FreightType
        {
            SATCHEL,
            CARTON,
            PALLET,
        };
        float cost()
        {
            return perKiloCost * weight;
        }
    private:
        freight (string set_address, float set_length, float set_width, float set_height, float set_weight);
        string address;
        float length;
        float width;
        float height;
        float weight;
        FreightType type;
        float perKiloCost;
        ~freight();
};

freight::freight (string set_address, float set_length, float set_width, float set_height, float set_weight)
{
    address = set_address;
    length = set_length;
    width = set_width;
    height = set_height;
    weight = set_weight;
    type = PALLET;
    perKiloCost = 1.00;
        {
            float volume = length * width * height;
            if(volume > MAX_PALLET_VOLUME)
            {
                type = PALLET;
                perKiloCost = PALLET_COST_PER_KILO;
            }
            else if(volume > MAX_CARTON_VOLUME)
            {
                type = CARTON;
                perKiloCost = CARTON_COST_PER_KILO;
            }
            else
            {
                type = SATCHEL;
                perKiloCost = SATCHEL_COST_PER_KILO;
            }
        }
}

freight::~freight()
{

}
```

Comment: `string address;` should be `std::string address;`, same for the parameter definition.

Comment: Oh wow. Completely forgot about std...

Comment: Also one question per question please.

Comment: Seems the above compiles now once there's a main() added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use qualified name `std::string`

```
freight(std::string set_address, float set_length, float set_width, float set_height, float set_weight):
```

Another problem is that you defined the constructor with parameters twice: one inside the class definition and other outside the class definition. Remove one definition.

Also you defined the destructor outside the class definition. You have at first to declare it at least in the class definition.

Comment: Yep I just fixed that bit up. Now there's errors that I haven't seen before.
test.cpp:64:1: error: redefinition of ‘freight::freight(std::string, float, float, float, float)’
 freight::freight (string set_address, float set_length, float set_width, float set_height, float set_weight)

test.cpp:22:6: error: ‘freight::freight(std::string, float, float, float, float)’ previously defined here
      freight(string set_address, float set_length, float set_width, float set_height, float set_weight):

test.cpp:73:19: error: definition of implicitly-declared ‘freight::~freight()’
 freight::~freight()

Comment: @DwayneH See my updfated post.

Comment: I fixed the second part, that was an oversight on my part. I'm having trouble seeing where the inside class definition begins and ends. That was part of the edits made to the code originally. Is it everything after the enum down to the start of private?

Comment: @DwayneH I am sorry I have not understood your question. You have to include the destructor declaration (or its definition) also in the class definition. The constructor and the enumeration are public in your class definition.

Comment: That's alright. I'll explain it a bit better. Is everything from:
freight(string set_address, float set_length, float set_width, float set_height, float set_weight):

Down to.

return perKiloCost * weight;

All part of the constructor?

Comment: @DwayneH After the constructor there is member function float cost()
{
        return perKiloCost * weight;
}

Comment: Ok I have updated the question with my current code, it seems like it's almost there aside from the weird errors.

Answer (score 1):

Use qualified `std::string` or propagate its namespace with `using namespace std;`.

Also, why are you *defining* then function *inline in the class declaration* and a second time *below it*?

Also, you did not *declare* the destructor in the *class declaration*.

Comment: In all honesty I'm not completely sure. This was code that was suggested to me as edits to a freight class I made that didn't quite suit my purpose, but it seemed like the formatting was off.